# Licence de mathématiques mais licence en droit

Tags: prépositions, éducation

On parle en général de [licence **de** mathématiques](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licence+en+math%C3%A9matiques%2Clicence+de+math%C3%A9matiques&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clicence%20en%20math%C3%A9matiques%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clicence%20de%20math%C3%A9matiques%3B%2Cc0) ou [**de** lettres](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licence+en+lettres%2Clicence+de+lettres&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clicence%20en%20lettres%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clicence%20de%20lettres%3B%2Cc0) mais de
[licence **en** droit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licence+en+droit%2Clicence+de+droit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clicence%20en%20droit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clicence%20de%20droit%3B%2Cc0) tandis que [l'histoire¹](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licence+en+histoire%2Clicence+d%27histoire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clicence%20en%20histoire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clicence%20d%20%27%20histoire%3B%2Cc0) et [la sociologie](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licence+en+sociologie%2Clicence+de+sociologie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clicence%20en%20sociologie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clicence%20de%20sociologie%3B%2Cc0) sont plus partagées. Pour la maîtrise, [**d'**histoire¹](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ma%C3%AEtrise+en+histoire%2C+ma%C3%AEtrise+d%27histoire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cma%C3%AEtrise%20en%20histoire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cma%C3%AEtrise%20d%20%27%20histoire%3B%2Cc0) l'emporte (et [**de** mathématiques](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ma%C3%AEtrise+en+math%C3%A9matiques%2Cma%C3%AEtrise+de+math%C3%A9matiques&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cma%C3%AEtrise%20de%20math%C3%A9matiques%3B%2Cc0) encore plus) tandis que [**de** et **en** sociologie](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ma%C3%AEtrise+en+sociologie%2Cma%C3%AEtrise+de+sociologie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cma%C3%AEtrise%20en%20sociologie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cma%C3%AEtrise%20de%20sociologie%3B%2Cc0) restent partagés, tout comme l'est [le droit](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ma%C3%AEtrise+en+droit%2Cma%C3%AEtrise+de+droit&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cma%C3%AEtrise%20en%20droit%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cma%C3%AEtrise%20de%20droit%3B%2Cc0).

D'où vient cette différence ? Est-ce une spécificité du droit qui a déteint sur certaines sciences sociales ? Y a-t-il des variations régionales ?

<sub>(Question motivée par un point soulevé dans des commentaires sous [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5915/bachelor-degree-in-french/24509#24509))</sub>

¹  <sub>Le lien ne marche pas quand il y a une apostrophe, il faut retaper la recherche.</sub>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52997/discussion-on-question-by-gilles-licence-de-mathematiques-mais-licence-en-droit).

Answer (score 3):

Le fait que les **deux** formes soient acceptées (on trouve par exemple *licence en droit* aussi bien *licence de droit*, même si l'une est plus fréquente que l'autre), n'indique-t'il pas tout simplement qu'il n'y a pas de raison profonde ? L'usage supporte simplement les deux.

Il existe parfois une autre forme, qui n'a pas été mentionnée jusqu'à présent: "*licence **ès**-lettres*". On utilisait également au XIXème siècle: "*baccalauréat **ès**-sciences*". Une [recherche rapide](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=licence%20en%20lettres%2Clicence%20de%20lettres%2C%20licence%20%C3%A8s%20lettres&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=7&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clicence%20en%20lettres%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clicence%20de%20lettres%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clicence%20%C3%A8s%20lettres%3B%2Cc0) montre que "***ès**-lettres*" est encore utilisé de nos jours, et ce, presque aussi fréquemment que "*licence **de** lettres*". On utilise parfois aussi "***ès**-sciences*". En revanche, "*licence **ès**-mathématiques*" et "*licence **ès**-droit*" sont inconnus.

De plus, il semble que les universités elle-mêmes utilisent "de", "en", et parfois rien du tout, en tout cas pas pour "Licence" et "Master". Quelques exemples:

- [Paris 8, Licences 2016-2018](http://www.univ-paris8.fr/Licences-2016-2017)
- [Université de Strasbourg, Licences](http://www.unistra.fr/formations/type-diplome/Licence)
- [Université de Marseille, Licences](http://formations.univ-amu.fr/ME3SMI.html)
- [Paris 8, Master Droit Privé](http://www.univ-paris8.fr/Master-Droit-prive)
- [Lyon 2, Masters](http://offreformation.univ-lyon2.fr/cdm/fr/fiche/objectifs/FRUAI0691775EPRME267)

Donc l'usage actuel semble utiliser trois, voire même quatre !, formes (suivant les domaines, et dans des proportions différentes), ce qui pour moi renforce l'idée qu'il n'y a peut-être "ni rime ni raison" qui expliquerait la différence de proportion notée par Gilles.

On pourrait aussi conclure qu'il y a bien différence dans les proportions, mais que cette différence n'est pas forcément significative en pratique, ou en tout, qu'il n'est pas possible de trouver une règle générale pour l'utilisation de "de" plutôt que de "en".

Il va être à mon avis difficile de trouver des raisons pour un phénomène aussi aléatoire.

***Addendum*** (consulter l'autre réponse sur la situation au Québec): on pourrait proposer le processus historique suivant: à l'origine, "ès" était le mot utilisé, qui est devenu "en" (avant le XVIIème?), puis encore plus récemment en France, "de" est passé dans l'usage de façon plus ou moins arbitraire. Suivant cette hypothèse, "en" serait plus ancien que "de". Cette hypothèse se tient assez bien au vu des données. Mais ceci n'explique pas *pourquoi* certaines matières utilisent maintenant "de", et d'autres "en".

***Note***: "**ès**" est une contraction, maintenant archaïque, de "en les/à l'intérieur des", ici [pour désigner une spécialité dans des titres officiels](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A8s). "*Doctorat ès lettres*" peut donc se comprendre comme "*doctorat en les lettres*". Le mot est attesté dès [1375-1400](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/%C3%A8s?idf=froissartXcbch;str=0).

Answer (score 3):

On est incapable d'établir un lien suffisant entre ce qu'on voit au Québec, le propos du *TLFi* et ce qu'on présente en France. Il s'agit donc d'un complément d'analyse régional.

---

Échantillon d'universités québécoises pour le [premier cycle](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871167) dans le domaine du droit :

- [UdeM](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/baccalaureat-en-droit/), [Uqam](https://etudier.uqam.ca/programme?code=7308), [Laval](https://www.ulaval.ca/les-etudes/programmes/repertoire/details/baccalaureat-en-droit-ll-b.html#description-officielle), [Sherbrooke](https://www.usherbrooke.ca/programmes/?id=p251) : Baccalauréat en
  droit.
- [McGill](http://www.mcgill.ca/law/fr/future) : Baccalauréat intégré en droit civil et en common
  law ([n.b.](http://www.mcgill.ca/cdo/employers/bcl/)).
- [Concordia](https://www.concordia.ca/fr/etudes/programmes-de-1er-cycle/Droit-societe-mineure.html) : Mineure en droit et société.

UdeM pour les disciplines mentionnées en question (le type est mentionné uniquement pour le bacc.) :

- [Baccalauréat en mathématiques](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/baccalaureat-en-mathematiques/) (type Baccalauréat ès sciences,
  voir aussi [McGill](http://www.mcgill.ca/undergraduate-admissions/fr/bachelor-science)) ; [Maîtrise en mathématiques](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/maitrise-en-mathematiques/) (intitulé) ;
  [Doctorat en mathématiques](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/doctorat-en-mathematiques/) (intitulé).
- [Baccalauréat en histoire](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/baccalaureat-en-histoire/) (type [Baccalauréat ès arts](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364187)) ;
  [Maîtrise en histoire](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/maitrise-en-histoire/) ; [Doctorat en histoire](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/doctorat-en-histoire/).
- [Baccalauréat en sociologie](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/baccalaureat-en-sociologie/) (type Baccalauréat ès sciences);
  [Maîtrise en sociologie (intitulé), M. Sc. (sociologie)](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/maitrise-en-sociologie/) en corps
  de texte ; [Doctorat en sociologie (Ph. D.), Ph. D.
  (sociologie)](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/doctorat-en-sociologie/).
- [Baccalauréat en littératures de langue française](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/baccalaureat-en-litteratures-de-langue-francaise/) (type
  Baccalauréat ès arts) ; [Maîtrise en littératures de langue
  française](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/maitrise-en-litteratures-de-langue-francaise/) ; [Programme de doctorat en littératures de langue
  française](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/doctorat-en-litteratures-de-langue-francaise/).
- Baccalauréat en droit (type Baccalauréat en droit) ; [Maîtrise en droit](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/maitrise-en-droit/) (intitulé) ;
  [Doctorat en droit](https://admission.umontreal.ca/programmes/doctorat-en-droit/).

À première vue dans ce petit échantillon du Québec, on utilise exclusivement la préposition *en*, et on mentionne des types de grades formels qui chapeautent la plupart des *programmes de [niveau] en [domaine]*. On garde à l'esprit que ces institutions et leur site web n'ont pas vocation à statuer sur les prépositions en langue française ; on consultera plutôt la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1874) (aussi [abréviations](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=1114)).

---

En droit spécifiquement, au Québec, on a traditionnellement le baccalauréat en droit dont le grade est LL. B. (par exemple [UdeM](https://admission.umontreal.ca/typo3temp/fichepdf/UdeM_Baccalaur%C3%A9at_en_droit-2017-02-02-002241.pdf) : « La réussite du programme donne droit au Baccalauréat en droit (LL. B.). »). Le sens du LL. est plus clair en anglais avec le [*Bachelor of Laws*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Laws) :

> [...] vient de l'expression latine *Legum Baccalaureus* (bachelier es
>   lois). "LL" est l'abréviation classique du génitif (complément de nom)
>   pluriel de *legum* [*sic, recte* : [lex](http://www.lexilogos.com/latin/gaffiot.php?q=lex)].
>
> Wikipédia, [Bachelor of Laws](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor_of_Laws) (Fr.)

Un législateur est possiblement [*legum scriptor*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lex#Latin), par exemple. On pense que si un générique pluriel se cachait derrière le domaine (lois, droit), que c'est *en* pour *en les* qui peut prédominer dans l'usage. On pense que c'est un choix du rendu du complément du nom en français selon qu'on a une vision latinisante ou non des grades, ou selon des étapes successives de développement des grades où cette influence est plus ou moins marquée. Il demande beaucoup plus d'expertise et ce n'est donc que pure spéculation.

Par ailleurs, le *TLFi* contient une note à [ès](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A8s), dont on a traité dans une [autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/24526), à l'effet que « [l]'usage semble quelque peu flottant dans les dénominations récentes des grades universitaires, qui, notamment devant les noms de spécialité commençant par s, mettent *ès* en concurrence avec *en* et avec *de* ou *des*. ».

Comment: Très intéressant. Le Québec utilise donc une nomenclature plus uniforme, et plus proche de "ès" ("_en_" qqch se comprend très bien comme "_dans_" qqch). Y'aurait-t-il un lien avec l'idée que la langue française au Québec a conservé certaines formes plus anciennes qu'en France? Dans cette optique, "de" ne deviendrait courant que "récemment" dans les titres officiels, alors que "en" serait plus ancien (plus proche de "ès" en Moyen Français).

Comment: Ce serait un élément de réponse à la question initiale de Gilles: à l'origine, "ès" était le mot utilisé, qui est devenu "en" (avant le XVIIème?), puis encore plus récemment en France, "de" est passé dans l'usage de façon plus ou moins arbitraire. Cette hypothèse se tient assez bien au vu des données.

Comment: Peut-être le droit étant plus "conservateur", a-t-il maintenu "en", alors que les mathématiques auraient plus facilement adopté "de"?

Comment: @Frank Peut-être dans ces eaux-là... Peut-être que c'est un espèce de phénomène de démocratisation de la préposition dans les grades quand on en discute plus usuellement, dans un texte. _Maîtrise en_ ressemble à un substantif générique, alors que _maîtrise de_ rappelle une forme plus verbale ou un nom composé, et dans ce sens peut-être met en valeur davantage la discipline. Ou on partait d'un truc très figé latinisant, ou déconnecté d'un français plus moderne et qu'on rejette.

Comment: Voir aussi en 1997 ds. la loi, où l'on a statué (pas pour la première fois, mais vastement) : [1](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000747697&categorieLien=cid#LEGIARTI000030340371), [2](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000382767&categorieLien=cid#LEGIARTI000030340306), [3](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000200660&categorieLien=cid#LEGIARTI000030339885), [4](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000200771&categorieLien=cid#LEGIARTI000030340344). Merci !

Comment: Pour une recherche fort approfondie dans un corpus normatif, on peut cibler de manière récursive deux liens : [Code de l'éducation](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichCode.do;jsessionid=0D0C01AFEEBAC644205BFF4142B7CE2E.tpdila14v_1?cidTexte=LEGITEXT000006071191&dateTexte=20170203) ; [ensemble normatif](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichSarde.do?reprise=true&fastReqId=1716295550&idSarde=SARDOBJT000007106190&page=1) pour les grades etc. On pourrait reculer jusqu'au décret de 1808 sur les universités et voir la progression (ou régression) du lexique au normatif micro, contra _ngram_.