# What are "premier cycle universitaire" and “baccalauréat”?

Tags: vocabulaire, québec, éducation

From my understanding, le premier cycle universitaire is essentially the equivalent of a Bachelor's degree. However, from my understanding, a Bachelor's degree is known as a baccalauréat.

Am I misunderstanding something?  Are "baccalauréat" and "le premier cycle universitaire" the same thing?  Are we talking about the same level of education?

I've looked around online, and am having a hard time finding authoritative sources, so sourced replies would be welcome.

#### Edit:

I am particularly interested in the Canadian system, not the French system.

Comment: [This question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/5915), although definitely not a duplicate of yours, might have some useful info (including Frank's chart and @jlliagre ’s link [in a comment] to [this page](http://www.education.gouv.fr/cid143/le-baccalaureat-premier-grade-universitaire.html), which states that the Bac is the “premier **grade** universitaire”)

Comment: I see in your profile that you're in Canada. Are you asking specifically about the Canadian education system, which I guess would likely be the Quebec system if you're asking about the French side of it? The current answers focus on France's system, which is different, so if that's not what you're asking about, you should specify.

Comment: @Kareen, good point.  Yes, I am interested in the Canadian system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In Canada**, a bachelor's degree is a *baccalauréat* in French. *Le premier cycle universitaire* refers generally to studies at the bachelor's level or below. This includes *le [certificat](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8488112)* ("certificate", 30 credits), *la [mineure](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299428)* ("minor", also 30 credits), *la [majeure](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299429)* ("major", 60 credits) and *le [baccalauréat](http://www.granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8872117)* ("bachelor's degree", 90 or 120 credits). However, most people do associate *le premier cycle* with the bachelor's degree. In English, one might refer to students of this cycle as "[undergraduates](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&srchtxt=UNDERGRADUATE&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)".

In Quebec, the earliest a typical student obtains a *baccalauréat* (barring exceptions) is around 22 years of age.

The Quebec university system, which is very similar to the rest of Canada's systems, has three cycles:

- First cycle (*premier cycle*) is generally bachelor's degree
- Second cycle (*deuxième cycle*) is generally master's degree (*maîtrise*)
- Third cycle (*troisième cycle*) is doctorate (*doctorat*)

You can find more detail on the cycles on the [Université du Québec en Outaouais's website](http://uqo.ca/international/systeme-universitaire-quebecois) or the [Université du Québec à Montréal's website](https://etudier.uqam.ca/etudiants-etrangers/systeme-education-universitaire-quebecois) (both in French).

Comment: Pouvez-vous mettre des âges typiques en regard de chaque (âge du bachelor's degree ...)? Cela faciliterait la comparaison avec la France et les US - on dirait que le système Québecois est à mi-chemin des deux.

Comment: @Frank Le système québécois est effectivement un peu plus oblique que système américain et les parcours peuvent diverger plus, mais je vais tenter le coup!

Comment: à quoi ressemble le curriculum? Quelle est la part de l'anglais, et la part du français?

Comment: @Frank Les cours du baccalauréat au Québec sont spécialisés. Il n'y a habituellement pas de cours de langues générales à ce niveau.

Comment: I'm trying to understand if _ bachelor's_ is our _ baccalauréat_. Ours is at the end of high-school. Is it the case for the Canadian _bachelor's_ too? Just to confirm.

Comment: @Frank No, a *bachelor's degree* in Canada and the US is a degree you get after 3 or 4 years of studies in a university, after you already have your high school diploma. A French Canadian *baccalauréat* is approximately the equivalent of a *licence*. There are a couple of small charts of equivalences at the bottom of the two last links I provided.

Comment: Thanks! That's a big difference, as _baccalauréat_ is unambiguously a high-school thing in France. Do you have a diploma granted at the end of high-school, or not?

Comment: @Frank Yes, we do. The high school diploma is Quebec is called *diplôme d'études secondaires*, or DES for short.

Answer (score 3):

**Au Québec** uniquement, en complément à la [réponse sélectionnée](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/24896), on peut présenter l'information qui semble avoir fait défaut un peu partout et à plus d'une reprise, et le point en amont permettant la comparaison avec la fameuse référence à BAC + [nombre d'années] :

> [...] Au Québec, le terme *licence*, remplacé vers 1970 par le terme
>   *baccalauréat*, sanctionnait la réussite du premier cycle universitaire de trois années.
>
> [ Grand dictionnaire terminologique (GDT), [*licence*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871167) ]

Ce que le [*baccalauréat*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8872117) sanctionne aujourd'hui tel que mentionné en réponse. Un article *Wikipédia* complet est dédié au système d'[éducation québécois](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89ducation_au_Qu%C3%A9bec). En résumé on a comme [niveaux d'enseignement](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89ducation_au_Qu%C3%A9bec#Niveaux_d.27enseignement) l'éducation primaire (années 1-6 à l'école primaire ; nommées première année, deuxième...), l'éducation secondaire (années 7-11 à l'école secondaire, à la polyvalente etc.; nommées première secondaire/secondaire 1, 2... etc.) menant à l'obtention du *Diplôme d'études secondaires* (DES) ou *professionnel* (DEP), puis le CÉGEP (années 1-3, au [Cégep](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299032)) menant généralement à l'obtention du *Diplôme d'études collégiales* (DEC). Quelqu'un qui a un parcours académique ne comportant aucune interruption depuis l'enfance et se destinant aux études universitaires accède normalement au *premier cycle universitaire* avec ces deux diplômes en main (DES, DEC). C'est l'obtention du DEC, clôturant l'éducation pré-universitaire, qui est le moment charnière qu'on peut utiliser pour comparer à la référence BAC + [nombre d'années] en France (par exemple Fr. BAC + 3 (licence) = Qc. DEC + 3 (baccalauréat)).

Answer (score 2):

**In France**, check out this official website: [CIEP](http://www.ciep.fr/en).

Also, this diagram might help:

[image]

Comment: -1 because your answer is specific to France whereas this question is specifically targeted to Quebec.

Comment: @ApplePie Pie Cette réponse était tout à fait correcte au moment où elle a été rédigée. Comme tout le monde peut le lire elle a été rédigée **avant** que la personne qui a posé la question ne prenne la peine de préciser qu'elle voulait une réponse spécifique au Québec. Seules les questions bien posées peuvent obtenir de bonnes réponses. Vote négatif arbitraire non justifié.

Answer (score 1):

**In France**, Before 2002 the "premier cycle universitaire" designated  the first two years at university at the end of which a student would get a diploma called [DEUG](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipl%C3%B4me_d%27%C3%A9tudes_universitaires_g%C3%A9n%C3%A9rales).

In 2002 there was a reform ([Réforme LMD](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9forme_Licence-Master-Doctorat) *Licence-Master-Doctorat*) whose main aim was to harmonize with European standards.  Since then the term "premier cycle universitaire" is hardly used, and when used it designates the fist three years at university, at the end of which a student is supposed to get his "[licence](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Licence_(France))" (*bachelor's degree* in English).

As mentioned before be careful as not to confuse the [baccalauréat](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baccalaur%C3%A9at_en_France) which in France one takes at the end of their secondary education with what is called a [bachelor's degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor's_degree) in some countries, and which is an exam taken after some years (depends on countries) at university.

Comment: @redahabsinpeach  Depuis le début du  siècle une quinzaine d'année l'expression « Processus de Bologne » fait partie du vocabulaire courant du milieu universitaire français (et belge à ma connaissance mais probablement d'autres...) qui en « subit » les conséquences. Le phénomène a / continue de faire couler de l'encre, il a son article sur [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processus_de_Bologne), etc.

Comment: Le terme master (emprunté au départ aux universités anglo-saxonne) était déjà utilisé par des écoles de commerce mais depuis Bologne il est inscrit dans le cursus universitaire. Avant Bologne, on parlait de « maîtrise » (BAC + 4), terme que je crois vous avez gardé au Québec ?

Comment: Merci pour les informations ! Oui, à ma connaissance la seule différence en est une de nomenclature, à savoir que la [licence](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8871167) en France soit le baccalauréat au Québec depuis 1970, autrement je reconnais _master_ complètement indépendamment de Bologne vu ma familiarité avec le nom du grade en langue anglaise, le fait que le mot soit usuel, et morphologiquement que j'y voie facilement la maîtrise qu'on a gardé, en effet... ça ressemblerait à "DEC + 4" en utilisant un raisonnement comparable (_Diplôme d'études collégiales_)...

Comment: Peut-on avoir la raison de ce vote négatif ? En quoi la réponse ne répond-elle pas à la question posée, réponse de plus rédigée avant que le questionneur ne précise qu'il s'agissait du Québec.

Comment: Pour une raison que je ne comprends pas, j'ai été avisé de votre dernier commentaire ?? Quand on écrit « Québec » dans un commentaire je suis avisé semble-t-il hahah. Merci.

Comment: @deLaDauversière Peut-être parce que vous êtes abonné au tag Québec ? Je ne pense pas que ce soit vous qui ayez mis un vote négatif, j'ai vu après coup que toutes les réponses faites avant que celui qui avait si mal posé sa question ne la modifie avait eu droit au même traitement.

Answer (score 0):

"Baccalauréat" is different from "Premier cycle universitaire". In France, you have to pass the "Baccalauréat" exam before you can enter university (at the end of "Lycée").